# Order table by the total count but do not lose the order by names

Tags: sql

I have a table,  consisting of 3 columns (Person, Year and Count), so for each person, there are several rows with different years and counts and the final row with total count. I want to keep the table ordered by Name, but also order it by the total count.

So the rows should be ordered by sum, but also grouped by the Person and ordered by year. When I am trying to order by sum, of course, both person and years are messed up. Is there a way to sort like this?

Comment: Wrong datamodel, you don't store different types of data (year and text) in the same column. Calculating the sum of several years is something that can be done in SQL when you need it, but you don't store that in your database. This also solves your problem, and many problems you didn't encounter yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've stored those "total" rows as well? Gosh! Why did you do that?

---

Anyway: if you

- *compute* rank for rows whose `year` column is equal to `'total'` and
- add `case` expression into the `order by` clause,

you might get what you want:

```
SQL> with sorter as
  2    (select name, cnt,
  3       rank() over (order by cnt) rnk
  4     from test
  5     where year = 'total'
  6    )
  7  select t.*
  8  from test t join sorter s on s.name = t.name
  9  order by s.rnk, case when year = 'total' then '9'
 10                       else year
 11                  end;

NAME YEAR         CNT
---- ----- ----------
John 2018           3
John 2019           2
John total          5
Bob  2017           2
Bob  2019           4
Bob  total          6

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, however, I meant that in the final table I need them to be sorted by total as well, e.g. in your example the first one will be John, since his total is smaller

Comment: Aha, that's what you meant ... OK, I think I got it. Edited the answer; have a look, please.

Comment: As you stored years as strings, 9 is sorted *after* all those 2017, 2018, 2021, ... years so TOTAL row comes as last for each name.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks

Comment: May I ask 1 more question, I have done what you have said, but in the case when 2 people have the same total count, therefore their rank is the same and as the result, they are mixed when printed. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: I think so; modify `order by s.rnk, t.name, case when ...` (add NAME as the 2nd sort option).